# Cookie created in JavaScript not updating when using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I am creating a cookie in JS using this:

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    var curCookie =
        name + "=" + value +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "/") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
    document.cookie = curCookie;
}

setCookie('AccountSelectedTab', '1');
```

when I then try to edit that cookie using ASP.NET:

```
Response.Cookies['AccountSelectedTab'].Value = 'some value';
```

It creates another cookie instead of changing it.

If I set the path to be the same on both cookies then I don't get a second one but the JS one doesn't update.

I guess I am missing something but need an idea as to what...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that your current JavaScript creates a session cookie, because you have omitted the `expires` and `max-age` flags?

Comment: Yes. I don't need it to save longer than the user is on the website.

Comment: What makes you think that it creates another cookie? I tested your code in a test website, and it works fine. Can you provide some more info?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you change your code behind as :

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("newCookie");

cookie.HttpOnly = false;
```

without this you won't be able to access cookies through Javascript.

Comment: How is this a solution to the OP's question?